# Laravel query builder advanced wheres AND, OR

Tags: mysql, select, laravel, where-clause, query-builder

```
 $query = new TableA;
 $query = $query->join('tableB', 'tableA.b_id', '=', 'tableB.id');
 $query = $query->where('tableB.something', '=', '1');
 $query = $query->where('tableA.something_else', '=', '2');
```

And it produces:

```
 WHERE something=1 AND something_else=2 AND .. AND....
```

BUT now - I need this:

```
 WHERE something=1 AND something_else=2 AND (city=city1 OR city=city2 OR city=city3) AND (country=country1 OR country=country2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: not entirely related to your question, but you should look into laravel relationships.  It'll save you so much code, and make it look nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [Advanced Wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres). For your example, it'd be something like this:

```
    ->where(function ($query) {
       $query->where('city', '=', city1)
             ->orWhere('city', '=', city2)
             ->orWhere('city', '=', city3);
    })->where(function ($query) {
       $query->where('country', '=', country1)
             ->orWhere('country', '=', country2);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick method. Read about raw expressions:

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions